# Extra Action Bar Displayed

Tags: android, android-actionbar

What I want to do is add an item to the contextual menu on an EditText.  What is happening is the contextual menu is displayed above the regular action bar.  I would like it to temporarily replace the regular action bar.

[Here is an image of the oddness that I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYFkV.png)

Here is the code relevant to the manipulation of the menu and action bar.

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.optionsMenu = menu;
    menu.clear();
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    switch (currentState) {
        case ACTIVITY_STATE_EDIT:
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_edit_quote, menu);
            break;
        case ACTIVITY_STATE_NEW:
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_edit_quote, menu);
            break;
    }
    updateSaveButtonState();
    return true;
}

//
// Implementation of ActionMode.Callback interface
//
MenuItem addSetKeyWordMenuItem(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem newItem = menu.add(0, ACTION_SET_KEYWORD, 0, "Set Keyword");
    newItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_vpn_key_white_48dp);
    newItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    return newItem;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    addSetKeyWordMenuItem(menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // addSetKeyWordMenuItem(menu);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == ACTION_SET_KEYWORD) {
        String newKey = quoteEditText.getText().subSequence(quoteEditText.getSelectionStart(), quoteEditText.getSelectionEnd()).toString();
        keyEditText.setText(newKey);
        quoteEditText.clearFocus();
        updateSaveButtonState();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void updateSaveButtonState() {
    // Prevent the user from saving when there is no keyword set.
    if (currentState == ACTIVITY_STATE_EDIT || currentState == ACTIVITY_STATE_NEW) {
        if (this.optionsMenu != null) {
            MenuItem saveItem = this.optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_save);
            if (saveItem != null) {
                boolean state = !quoteEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty();
                saveItem.setEnabled(state);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set actionMode overlay in the themes as below:

```
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

Comment: Thanks.  After sorting out just what theme was being used this did the trick.